# Methods firing out of order

Tags: ios, swift, function, methods, healthkit

I have `updateHeight`, `updateWeight`, and `updateBMI` methods in my `HealthAlgorithm` class.  I then try to call them in order in `ViewController.swift`

`HealthAlgorithm.swift`:

```
//MARK: Properties
var healthManager:HealthManager?
var kUnknownString = "Unknown"
var bmi:Double?
var height:HKQuantitySample?
var weight:HKQuantitySample?

func updateHeight() {       

    // 1. Construct an HKSampleType for weight
    let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight)

    // 2. Call the method to read the most recent weight sample
    HealthManager().readMostRecentSample(sampleType!, completion: { (mostRecentHeight, error) -> Void in

        if( error != nil )
        {
            print("Error reading height from HealthKit Store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        var heightLocalizedString = self.kUnknownString
        self.height = mostRecentHeight as? HKQuantitySample
        print(self.height)
        // 3. Format the height to display it on the screen
        if let meters = self.height?.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.meterUnit()) {
            let heightFormatter = NSLengthFormatter()
            heightFormatter.forPersonHeightUse = true
            heightLocalizedString = heightFormatter.stringFromMeters(meters)
        }
    })
}

func updateBMI(){
    if weight != nil && height != nil {
        // 1. Get the weight and height values from the samples read from HealthKit
        let weightInKilograms = weight!.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.gramUnitWithMetricPrefix(.Kilo))
        let heightInMeters = height!.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.meterUnit())
        bmi  = ( weightInKilograms / ( heightInMeters * heightInMeters ) )
    }
    print("BMI: ",bmi)
}
```

I call these methods in `ViewController.swift` like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    HealthAlgorithm().updateHeight()
    HealthAlgorithm().updateWeight()
    HealthAlgorithm().updateBMI()
}
```

The problem is that BMI is returned as `nil`.  The reason this is happening is that the `updateBMI` method is firing before the `updateHeight` and `updateWeight` method.

I use `print(self.height)` right after I define the variable in the `updateHeight` method, and I use `print("BMI: ", bmi)` right after I define the bmi variable in the `updateBMI` method.  Since I am calling `updateHeight` first, `print(self.height)` should happen before `print("BMI: ", bmi)`, but for some reason, the `BMI: nil` is getting returned first which makes no sense to me.

Comment: The methods are not being called out of order. The problem is that the function completes asynchronously. You need to call dependent code from the completion handler

Comment: So the `updateBMI` function is being called while `updateHeight` is still running?

Comment: `updateHeight` returns before the completion handler is called, so the answer is "almost definitely".

Comment: Basically, your code doesn't guarantee which will get called first. The simplest solution is to call `updateBMI` from the end of the `updateWeight` completion handler, and similarly call `updateWeight` when `updateHeight` is done. There are also more robust solutions for similar problems, for example you could solve this using `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue.  Managed to get it working by calling each function in order once the prerequisite ones have completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods are not being called out of order. The problem is that the function completes asynchronously. You need to call dependent code from the completion handler.